# Django email: Get receiver in body

Tags: python, django, django-email

I am using `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send mail to a list of recipients.

```
context = Context({'cc': cc, 'link': link})
    html_template = loader.get_template('email_new.html')
text_template = loader.get_template('email_new.txt')
from_email = 'afeld <afeld@has_questions.com>'
recipient_list = ['%s <%s>' % (e.full_name(), e.email()) for e in cc.not_responded()]
cc_list = ['%s <%s>' % (e.full_name(), e.email()) for e in cc.notification_recipients()]
message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject,
    text_template.render(context),
    from_email,
    to=recipient_list,
    cc=cc_list
)
```

Is it possible to get the recipient of an email inside the body? Something that would look like in my email.html

```
dear {{ recipient }}

from afeld
```

How would I get `{{ recipient }}` from recipient_list?

Comment: this approach is correct

Comment: @e4c5 what do you mean? is recipient a reserved word?

Comment: did I say anything like that? I said this approach is correct. You didn't say whether you had a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand the approach is generally correct, but I am confused where EmailMultiAlternatives is looping over each recipient, and how can I pull that from EmailMultiAlternatives into the email's body

Comment: as I said post an MCVE you don't have any variable named recipient in your code

Comment: That is what I am asking. How would I get {{ recipient }} from recipient_list?

Comment: as I said post an MCVE  you haven't shown where your context comes from